# Embed Segue not backwards compatible

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5, uistoryboard

I have added Embed-Segues in my App and I just realized that this is not compatible to iOS 5.0.

I get the following error on Startup:

```
'NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException', 
reason: 'Could not instantiate class named UIStoryboardEmbedSegueTemplate'
```

Before I had my own custom "EmbedSegue" class which does pretty much the same thing.

Is there a way to kind of bridge this in iOS 5.0 or do I have to revert the changes that I've made?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It did turn out that the Embed segue is an iOS 6.0 only feature. It is a shame that Xcode does not warn me here, having the Target OS Version set to > 5.0.

Comment: This is incorrect: the embed segue is iOS 6 and up. See for instance http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14432310/embed-segue-ios-5

Comment: @ankstastic, I think that's what Besi meant to say, because your opinion is also implied by his question: "I just realized that [embed segues] is not compatible to iOS 5.0". So the 5.0 in his answer is probably just a typo and it should instead read "Embed segue is an iOS 6.0 only feature".

Comment: @anktastic & Daniel you guys are right, I updated my answer. cheers.