# How can I use an Embed Segue in iOS 5?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

iOS 6 introduced the Embed Segue, allowing custom container controllers to be used in Storyboards. Is there anyway to duplicate this for iOS 5?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I duplicated the functionality by subclassing UIStoryboardSegue.

In Interface Builder, I create a custom segue and set its' class to my subclass (QCEmbedSegue). In my parent view controller's `viewDidLoad`, I call `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender`.

QCEmbedSegue simply overrides `perform`:

```
- (void)perform
{
    [self.sourceViewController addChildViewController:self.destinationViewController];
    [[self.sourceViewController view] addSubview:[self.destinationViewController view]];
    [self.destinationViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self.sourceViewController];
}
```

http://www.quentamia.com/blog/embed-segue-in-ios-5/

Comment: Needless to say, that only works properly if the child scene is to be added to the top level view of the parent controller. But it was a noble attempt.

Comment: @Rob Very true. In my situation, that's all I require. It could be built upon to allow insertion anywhere in the view hierarchy.

Answer (score 9):

The challenge here is that the child view controller's view is often to be added as a subview of some container view of the parent view controller. Since you can't have segues from random `UIView` controls, that defies creating segues from a `UIView` container view to the child's scene. Thus, you just have to write the code yourself.

Fortunately, it's just those four lines of code referenced in [Adding a Child Controller](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH18-SW13) from the *View Controller Programming Guide.* Personally, I'd might even modify that code slightly, having the following method defined in my view controller:

```
- (void) displayChildController:(UIViewController*)childController
                inContainerView:(UIView *)containerView
{
   [self addChildViewController:childController];                 // 1
   childController.view.frame = containerView.bounds;             // 2
   [containerView addSubview:childController.view];
   [childController didMoveToParentViewController:self];          // 3
}
```

I have, though, done custom segues for changing the active child controller from one scene to the next, but it essentially just a variation of the code listed later in the above referenced document. But that's not an embed segue question, so that's not relevant here

Comment: How can you do this while still using iOS 6 container views? I was expecting that the segue would fail, but instead Apple hard-crashes when instantiating the UIViewController. (serious hackery there from Apple? I'm surprised that an incompatible, app-breaking "embed segue" was the best thing they could come up with here :()

Comment: @Adam Let's move this to chat: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36209/adam-and-rob-segues-and-container-views-in-ios-6