# I have made an app but now I'm told it is to be backwards compatible with previous iOS versions

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6

I'm new to writing apps but am slowly getting to grips with it. I finished an app I made but now the client tells me it needs to be compatible with `iOS 5`, too. I have used a lot of `iOS 6` features that seemingly are not backwards compatible.(Embed Segue, Social Framework, Tint Colour etc.)

Is there any easy way to make these work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as Embed Segue goes there is an answer to that here:
[Embed Segue - iOS 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14432310/embed-segue-ios-5)

For the social framework you just need to make the framework link optional, by changing it from "required" in the target>summary section of your project overview. Then using an if statement to check software version before using any of the API.

Check device version:

```
NSString *ver = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];
```

Comment: Apple advises that you do NOT do that. Do not use the system version to draw conclusions about what features are available. Instead, test against the features themselves.

Answer (score 1):

You should look at [Deploymate](http://www.deploymateapp.com) to catch some of the less than obvious API calls that aren't available for an iOS 5 deployment target.  It will show you specific lines that use an incompatible or unavailable API in a nice UI.